# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetimepicker

Getting an error that has me stumped. I'm assuming it's something simple but can't seem to figure this one out, this is the code that is causing the error:

```
if ((string) _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value != string.Empty && _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value != null) {
     _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value = null;
}
```

When clicking on the search button in my windows form, this is what I get popping up:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the type of the nullable-type instance of `_nullableDateTimePicker1` is `DateTime`, which is not a string; you would need to compare with a `DateTime` or convert that to a string.

So, in the simplest sense:

```
_nullableDateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() != string.Empty
```

However, beware the danger of not checking `HasValue`, as this would cause a `NullReferenceException` if `Value` is `null`; So, your check is a little backwards.

And even then, if it *wasn't* `null`, you'd have a `DateTime.MinValue`, and so `ToString` wouldn't return an empty string. Therefore, check for `null` on the nullable thing, and if not `null`, compare to `DateTime.MinValue` (unless there's a quirk specifically in your code which means it could have a *different* 'default'.

Comment: This will always be true, because `DateTime` always has a value (if not null).

Comment: @DavidS. I misinterpreted your comment at first, thanks for the input.

Comment: yes, but if `_nullableDateTimePicker1.HasValue`, the check `_nullableDateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() != string.Empty` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

`if ((string) _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value .....`

Probably, `_nullableDateTimePicker1.Value` returns a `DateTime`. As the message explains, you can't directly cast a `DateTime` to a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In this part `(string) _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value != string.Empty` you are trying to cast value to string. But `Value` is `DateTime`. The second part of this if is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
(string) _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value
```

throws the exception when _nullableDateTimePicker1 is null.

Don't use `(string)` when trying to check if value is not null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `_nullableDateTimePicker1` object is a `Nullable<DateTime>` (`DateTime?`), in which case you're getting this error because you can't cast it to a string.

```
(string) _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value
```

It looks like you're just trying to ensure that it has a valid DateTime, in which case you only need to do the null check. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do that's my advice.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
if (_nullableDateTimePicker1.Value != null && Convert.ToString(_nullableDateTimePicker1.Value) != string.Empty) {
     _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTimePicker.Value returns DateTime type you cannot cast it string, what you need is to conver to string.

```
string dateTime = _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
```

so your code will be:

```
string dateTime = _nullableDateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime)) 
{
    dateTime = null; 
 }
```

I am not sure about setting the DateTimePicker value to null.